# How to use arrow keys in mzscheme/guile REPL?

Tags: terminal, read-eval-print-loop, guile

When I'm typing in the REPL of guile or mzscheme

```
(define x 15)
```

and then press  arrow key I get
    (define x 15)^[[D

Is it a terminal problem? or something needs to be configured? It's painful to rewrite a line for a simple edit

Answer (score 16):

I found the answer for Guile, adding this in `~/.guile` will cut it:

```
(use-modules (ice-9 readline))
(activate-readline)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what guile is, but for mzscheme, you can input

```
(require readline)
```

To interactively enable the arrow-key behavior you're looking for. To enable this behavior when the REPL starts, run it using

```
mzscheme -il readline
```